# Umlauted Characters are not properly shown after updating TYPO3 to 6.2

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.1.x, typo3-6.2.x, typo3-4.5

I've updated my TYPO3 website from 4.1 to 6.2.9. Now the Umlauted Characters [German Letters] are not shown properly. Is there any Idea to fix that.

Comment: Have you checked the documentation? http://wiki.typo3.org/UTF-8_support (notice the note on top, which applies to your case)

Comment: can you brief what's the issue. I've checked the localconf file I didn't set any variables like $TYPO3_CONF_VARS['BE']['forceCharset']

Comment: You basically need to make sure all Apache and php.ini are set to utf-8, and have your mysql database in utf-8 format (you can use `SHOW TABLE STATUS` to check the collation). That page I linked gives all the information needed, but it's way beyond what would be acceptable for Stack Overflow, since it's a configuration issue for a software package, and not a programming question

Comment: And how about your database ? is this UTF-8 (tables and columns?)

Comment: @biesior: It's utdf-8-general ci

Comment: @Hoja.M.A Are the tables really using that encoding? I've had it that the data was encoded as utf8, but instead of an umlaut, something like `Ã¼` was stored in the database (correctly encoded, not a unicode character displayed using the wrong encoding). What helped in that case was to export the database using mysqldump with `--default-character-set=latin1`, then replacing all occurrences of `CHARSET latin1` with `CHARSET utf8` in the dump. After that, a reimport produced a correct database. Do it on a copy, of course.

Comment: yeah I've tried that way too..

Comment: Also I've used utf-8 convert extension in TYPO3. But it ruined my tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I experienced similar troubles when upgrading from 4.1 to 4.2. The following paragraphs are notes from my blog. Hope it helps.

**Updating from TYPO3 4.1 (and earlier versions) to 4.2 (and later)**

Some DB fields in 4.1 are of type BLOB (for example the TS templates). Most of these fields get converted to TEXT in 4.2. Now think about the following scenario, which seems to be common. The template was saved using TYPO3 4.1 and a DB using latin1 (ISO-8859-X) as charset. Then the DB converted to UTF-8 and TYPO3 was configured accordingly. You think you're finished because everything works will. But in most cases, there's still some latin1 formatted data in the BLOB fields. You just don't see. Once you upgrade TYPO3 to 4.2, these BLOBs get converted to TEXT, assuming the data is UTF-8. But it's latin1, because BLOB was not converted before. The result is a broken template. Lots of people in the mailing lists complain about whole parts missing. The reason is invalid non ascii characters (like umlauts äöüé¢ etc), which break the template view.

**How to avoid that?**

If you change the charset of TYPO3 and/or your DB, convert those BLOB fields which would have been changed by the TYPO3 update to TEXT before converting the charset or make sure to convert the BLOB data otherwise.

More about UTF-8 and older versions of TYPO3: https://stmllr.net/blog/thinking-about-utf-8-character-set-conversion-in-typo3/ Creative Commons License CC BY-SA 3.0